# Length of checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm new to R and I have a little problem please.

I have an huge data frame (250000 rows/190 columns) named BI14, and to display datas faster, I would like create a new data frame if only one box is checked.

Example : I check the town 2 check box, so, when I'll click the datas tab, the program will create a data frame from B14 named BI14_02 and will display datas of this data frame instead of the huge data frame. Another case : if I check the third county, the program will create a data frame named BI14_East.
If I check more than one box in County or Town tab or if I choose the Country tab, the huge data frame will be used and the datas will be displayed when I will click on the datas tab too. Excepted if I can create a new data frame for each checked box, but I suppose it would be too difficult to use the "NROW" instruction in several data frames at the same time an total up for a newbie like me.

So, I thought that it would be better to use "length" instruction to determinate if one or more check boxes are checked, but I need your help please.

This is the Ui.R code :

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "TEST",titleWidth = 500
                  ), # dashboardHeader close

  dashboardSidebar(## Sidebar content
    sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Level", tabName = "level", icon = icon("arrow-down")),
    menuSubItem("Country",icon = icon("globe"), tabName = "country"),
    menuSubItem("County",icon = icon("circle-o"), tabName = "county"),
    menuSubItem("Town",icon = icon("spinner"), tabName = "town"),
    menuItem("datas", tabName = "datas", icon = icon("list-alt")),
    menuItem("Maps", tabName = "maps", icon = icon("th"))
           ) # sidebarMenu close
              ), # f. de dashboardSidebar

  # Body content
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(# Country tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "country",
        fluidRow(
            box(title = "Click on datas tab", width = 9, 
                 background = "olive")
                ) # fluidRow close
            ), # tabItem close

  # County tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "county",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Counties", width = 3, solidHeader = TRUE,
              status = "primary",
              checkboxGroupInput("dynamic_counties", label = "",
                          choices = list("First county"  = "North",
                                         "Second county" = "South",
                                         "Third county" = "East"))
              ) # box close
                ) # fluidRow close
        ), # tabItem close

  # Town tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "town",
          #h4("Check one or more box(es)",              
          checkboxGroupInput(
              "dynamic", label = h4("Check one or more box(es)"),
            choices = list("01. Town 1"  =     "01", "02. Town 2" = "02",
                           "03. Town 3" = "03", "04. Town 4" = "04",
                           "05. Town 5" = "05", "06. Town 6" = "06",
                           "07. Town 7" = "07", "08. Town 8" = "08",
                           "09. Town 9" = "09", "10. Town 10" = "10",
                           "11. Town 11" = "11", "12. Town 12" = "12"))

        ), # tabItem close

  tabItem(tabName = "datas",
          fluidRow(
            box(title = "General datas", solidHeader = TRUE,
                         status = "primary",
                DT::dataTableOutput("df"))
                  ) # fluidRow close
          ) # tabItem close
     ) # tabItems close
  ) # dashboardBody close
) # dashboardPage close
```

In the Server.R, I have that but there's an error and I don't manage to resolve it :

```
observe({town<-renderText({input$dynamic})
 if (length(input$dynamic) = 1){paste("BI14_",town)<-subset(BI14,PC %in%
 input$dynamic)}})
```

I suppose it's easy to do but as I'm learning R...

Thank you very much for any help.

Have a good day.

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, and identify the specific problem that you have encountered.

Comment: In your `if` statement, it should be `==`, not `=` (i.e. an equality test, not an assignment)